# Subscript out of range error with an array - no idea why?

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I have declared an array as such `Dim rArray() As Variant`but when i try and use the values that is stored in it (as shown below) I get a subscript out of range error. The `UBound(rArray)`and `LBound(rArray)` both returns values 14 and 1, but the error occurs at the `Debug.Print` line.

If I use the for statement as below

```
For Each rArr in rArray
```

then it works without issues, but for the purposes I am creating this array I need the flexibility to select each item stored in that order- meaning I need to refer to them using subscripts.

I have tried multiple ways to try and solve this with no luck and spend almost half my day on this one issue. Could anyone point out what I need to change to get this to work.

```
Set rng = Range("D4", Range("D4").End(xlDown))
rng.NumberFormat = "0"
rArray = rng.Value

For x = UBound(rArray) To LBound(rArray) Step -1
    Debug.Print rArray(x)
Next x
```

Edit: another fact worth mentioning is that he array is declared and used within a Function but it is not passed from or to the function. Can't arrays be declared and used in Functions?

Comment: i'm no expert, but what if you print x, and see what value of x the problem occurs at

Comment: Thanks. I don't have to print x, while debugging  I can see the value of x is 14 which is where the loop starts from - there are 14 items stored in the array.

Comment: as a troubleshooting step, what if you remove the loop and try for x=13? and try for x=1

Comment: Tried that - and I get the same error - Subscript out of range. Which is what led me to think that it is the way I am storing the values in the array.

Comment: I don't know, I don't really use VBA, but you've asked the question well and it sounds trivial enough, you'll get a reply.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you assign worksheet values to a variant array, you *always* end up with a 2-D array that is *1* based (e.g. 1 to something, 1 to something; *never* 0 to something, 0 to something). If you are getting values from a single column the second Rank is merely 1 to 1.

This can be proven with the following.

```
Dim x As Long, rArray As Variant, rng As Range

Set rng = Range("D4", Range("D4").End(xlDown))
rng.NumberFormat = "0" 'don't really understand why this is here
rArray = rng.Value

Debug.Print LBound(rArray, 1) & ":" & UBound(rArray, 1)
Debug.Print LBound(rArray, 2) & ":" & UBound(rArray, 2)

For x = UBound(rArray, 1) To LBound(rArray, 1) Step -1
    Debug.Print rArray(x, 1)
Next x
```

So you need to ask for the element in the first rank of the array; it is insufficient to just ask for the element.

Comment: Thanks again Jeeped. So if I change the array to Integer `Dim rArray () As  Integer` then it should work right - but it's not?

Comment: I honestly don't think you can stuff worksheet values into anything but a variant array unless you loop through the cells and populate the array individually. Sometimes out-of-the-box thinking just plain won't work. Stick with variant arrays.

Comment: Thank You! Appreciate the time and effort. I was asking because I have never worked with 2-D arrays before, so that might be a little more time consuming for me. But I am happy to learn - just on a tight time constraint.

Comment: Worked like a charm - thanks again. Should have posted here before I tried applying my little knowledge.